# Implementing linked list

Tags: c++, loops, data-structures, linked-list, c++17

I am creating a linked list but after printing it I am only getting the last element in an unending loop here is the code
I guess there is some error in creating the Linked list how to solve it

[Link to my code my linked List](https://onlinegdb.com/qfKjL0JXH)

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;    // for data component
    node* next;  // to hold addr of next 
}*head_first=NULL;

void create(int* a, int n) // a is array and n is sizeof
{
    node *newnode,*temp;
    
    newnode=new node(); 
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        newnode->data=a[i];
        newnode->next=NULL;
        
        
        if(head_first==NULL){
           temp=head_first=newnode;
           cout<<"head assigned"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
            cout<<i<<" node created"<<endl;
        }
    }
}

void dis(node *p){
    while(p!=NULL){
        cout<< p->data <<endl;
        p=p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    
    int a[]={10,20,30,40,50,60};
    int size=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    create(a,size);
   dis(head_first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like copy-pasting code into the question itself, and describing the problems you have with it.

Comment: I also recommend you take this as a good opportunity to learn how to *debug* your programs. Like for example using a *debugger* to step through the program statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend you do the debugging while drawing your list using pencil and paper, draw boxes for the nodes and arrows for the pointers. Erase and redraw arrows as you modify the pointers. That should hopefully make it a lot clearer.

Comment: Can you tell the "unending loop" happens in which function or method ? Which loop in which function is running forever ?

Comment: Talking about pencil and paper, if you haven't done it then *starting* by using only pencil and paper to draw up some sample lists and perform the operations on them is generally a good idea to do, long before you even start to write code. When you think you got it to work on paper, transform the operations into code, but only one little bit at a time, with building with extra warnings enabled (treated as errors that *must* be fixed) and testing before implementing the next bit. In your example, make sure the addition of the first node works before going on to the next.

Comment: [Continued] Then test with adding only one node, two nodes, three nodes. Every time something breaks you bring out the debugger, the paper where you written down the operations, and a blank piece of paper to see what really happens.

Comment: On another note (but unrelated to your problem), `NULL` is the old C-compatibility macro for null pointers. In C++ you should use `nullptr`.

Comment: Lastly, a hint about the problem: When and where do you create new nodes? How many nodes to you add? How many nodes do you actually create? Think about that while you step through in the debugger. (I figured it out with some [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).)

Comment: By looking to your program, your node is pointing itself... I think this is the reason why infinite loop is going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used same reference; that's the reason your code always updates the same memory location value and finally gives last value.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;    // for data component
    node* next;  // to hold addr of next 
}*head_first=NULL;

void create(int* a, int n) // a is array and n is sizeof
{
    node *newnode,*temp;
    
    newnode=new node(); 
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         newnode=new node(); 
        newnode->data=a[i];
        newnode->next=NULL;
        
        
        if(head_first==NULL){
           temp=head_first=newnode;
           cout<<"head assigned"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
            cout<<i<<" node created"<<endl;
        }
    }
}

void dis(node *p){
    while(p!=NULL){
        cout<< p->data <<endl;
        p=p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    
    int a[]={10,20,30,40,50,60};
    int size=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    create(a,size);
   dis(head_first);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside of the raw pointer and nullptr issue, I noticed that your node points itself. I think the code have to be modified like this:

```
void create(int* a, int n) // a is array and n is sizeof
{
    node *newnode,*temp;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        newnode=new node(); 
        newnode->data=a[i];
        newnode->next=NULL;
        
        
        if(head_first==NULL){
           temp=head_first=newnode;
           cout<<"head assigned"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
            cout<<i<<" node created"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you got that .
The problem raised I wasn't creating a new node so only last value was being displayed
Thanks for the solution and suggestion about NULL.

Comment: @Athrav_N Other than that, if you use raw pointer and naked new, be sure to delete them properly or you will face memory leak problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the errors that you get, are of course resulting from some wrong coding implementation. And those have been corrected already in other answers.

But for me the biggest problem is the wrong design.

Obviously you are mixing up "Node" with the "linked list". In real world applications the "Node" is a part of a linked list. In object oriented language we have a "has a" relation. So, a linked list has a Node.

Additionally, the whole "Node" functionality would be encapsulated in the linked list. So, the "Node" would NOT be visible to the outside world.

If we interact with a linked list to store or retrive values and such, we would never know about (and even not be interested in) the internas like a "Node".

And, maybe because of that suboptimal design approach, you will create errors.

So, maybe it would be a good idea to refactor your design, and after that, implement it in some better way. For example, use classes, no global avariables and no free functions to operate on list data.

To give you an idea on what could be done, I will show you some implementation of a singly linked list and a double linked list.

Singly Linked List:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>

// Very simple implementation of a forward list
template <class T>
class SinglyLinkedList {

    // The node
    struct Node {
        T data{};     // Data. Would normally be a templated argument
        Node* next{};   // And the pointer to the next node

        Node(const T& i, Node* n = nullptr) : data(i), next(n) {}; // Simple constructor to set a value and next pointer
    };

    Node* head{};       // This is the start of the list
    // It would be advisable to have a tail pointer. We use the more inefficient approach here
    Node* getLast() const { Node* n{ head }; while (n and n->next) n = n->next; return n; }

public:
    // Constructor / Destructor --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~SinglyLinkedList() { clear(); }

    // Default constuctor
    SinglyLinkedList() {}   // Default

    // From an initialization list
    SinglyLinkedList(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear();  for (const T& i : il) push_back(i); } // From initializer list

    // Copy constructor
    SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }

    // Move constructor. Will steal the elements from the other 
    SinglyLinkedList(SinglyLinkedList&& other) noexcept { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }

    // Assignment operator
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }

    // Move assignment operator 
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (SinglyLinkedList&& other) { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }

    // Housekeeping --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void clear() { Node* tmp{ head }; while (tmp) { Node* toDelete{ tmp }; tmp = tmp->next; delete toDelete; } head = nullptr; }
    int empty() const { return head == nullptr; }
    int size() const { int k{}; Node* n{ head }; while (n) { ++k; n = n->next; } return k; }

    // Modify content --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void push_front(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); n->next = head; head = n; };
    void push_back(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); Node* l = getLast(); if (l) l->next = n; else head = n; }
    void pop_front() { if (head) { Node* tmp = head->next; delete head; head = tmp; } }
    void pop_back() { // This is a little bit more difficult in a singly linked list
        if (head) {
            Node* n{ head }, * previous{};
            while (n and n->next) {
                previous = n;
                n = n->next;
            }
            delete n;
            if (previous)
                previous->next = nullptr;
            else
                head->next = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // Access elements --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    T& front() const { return head ? head->data : 0; };
    T back() const { Node* n = getLast(); return n ? n->data : 0; }

    // Add iterator properties to class ---------------------------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {                           // Local class for iterator
        Node* iter{};                           // Iterator is basically a pointer to the node
        Node* head{};

        // Define alias names necessary for the iterator functionality
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Constructor
        iterator() {}
        iterator(Node* n, Node* h) : iter(n), head(h) {}

        // Dereferencing
        reference operator *() const { return iter->data; }
        pointer operator ->() const { return &iter->data; }

        // Aithmetic operations
        iterator& operator ++() { if (iter) iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator ++(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; ++* this; return temp; }

        // Clumsy subtratcion
        iterator& operator --() { Node* tmp = head; while (tmp and tmp->next != this->iter) tmp = tmp->next; iter = tmp;  return *this; }
        iterator operator --(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; --* this; return temp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this;
        };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this;
        };

        // Comparison
        bool operator != (const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; }
        bool operator == (const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; }
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return iter < other.iter; }
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return iter > other.iter; }
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return iter <= other.iter; }
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return iter >= other.iter; }

        // Difference. Also complicated, because no random access
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const {
            difference_type result{};
            Node* n{ iter };
            while (n and n != other.iter) {
                ++result;
                n = n->next;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    // Begin and end function to initialize an iterator
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(nullptr, head); }

    // Functions typcical for forward lists ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Easy, becuase we can operate form the current iterator and do not need the "previous" element
    iterator insertAfter(iterator& pos, const T& i) {
        iterator result(nullptr, head);
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* n = new Node(i, pos.iter->next);
            pos.iter->next = n;
            result.iter = n;
        }
        return result;
    }
    iterator eraseAfter(iterator& pos) {
        iterator result(nullptr, head);
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* tmp = pos.iter->next->next;
            delete pos.iter->next;
            pos.iter->next = tmp;
            result.iter = pos.iter->next;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
// Test/Driver Code
int main() {

    // Example for initilizer list
    SinglyLinkedList<int> sllbase{ 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    // Show move constructor
    SinglyLinkedList<int> sll(std::move(sllbase));

    // Add some values in the front
    sll.push_front(4);
    sll.push_front(3);
    sll.push_front(2);
    sll.push_front(1);

    // Delete 1st element (Number 1)
    sll.pop_front();
    // Delete last element
    sll.pop_back();

    // Use a std::algorithm on our custom linked list. Works because we have an interator
    SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator iter = std::find(sll.begin(), sll.end(), 8);
    ++iter;
    --iter;

    // Now add an element after 8
    iter = sll.insertAfter(iter, 88);
    // And delete the 9
    iter = sll.eraseAfter(iter);

    // Use range based for loop. Works because, we have iterators
    for (int i : sll)
        std::cout << i << ' ';


    // Reverse Output
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::reverse_iterator<SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator> riter = std::make_reverse_iterator(sll.end());
    std::reverse_iterator<SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator> riterEnd = std::make_reverse_iterator(sll.begin());

    for (; riter != riterEnd; ++riter)
        std::cout << *riter << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

---

Double linked list. Similar to `std::list`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a header file -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Type trait helper to identify iterators --------------------------------------------------------
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// The List class ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class List {
    // Sub class for a Node -----------
    struct Node {
        Node* next{};
        Node* previous{};
        T data{};
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p, const T& d) : next(n), previous(p), data(d) {}
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p) : next(n), previous(p) {}
        Node() {}
    };

    // Private list data and functions --------
    size_t numberOfElements{};
    Node* head{};
    void init() { head = new Node(); head->next = head; head->previous = head; numberOfElements = 0; }

public:
    struct iterator;    // Forward declaration

    // Constructor --------------------
    List() { init(); }
    explicit List(const size_t count, const T& value) { init(); insert(begin(), count, value); };
    explicit List(const size_t count) { init(); insert(begin(), count); }
    template <typename Iter>
    List(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { init(); insert(begin(), first, last); }
    List(const List& other) { init(), insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); };
    List(List&& other) : head(other.head), numberOfElements(other.numberOfElements) { other.init(); }
    List(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { init(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }
    template <int N> List(const T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }
    template <int N> List(T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }


    // Assignment ---------------------
    List& operator =(const List& other) { clear(); insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); return *this; }
    List& operator =(List&& other) { clear(); head = other.head; numberOfElements = other.numberOfElements; other.init(); return *this; }
    List& operator =(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }

    void assign(const size_t count, const T& value) { clear(); insert(begin(), count, value); }
    void assign(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }
    template <typename Iter> void assign(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { clear(); insert(begin(), first, last); }
    template <int N> void assign(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> void assign(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }

    // Destructor ---------------------
    ~List() { clear(); }

    // Element Access -----------------
    T& front() { return *begin(); }
    T& back() { return *(--end()); }

    // Iterators ----------------------
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head->next, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(head, head); }

    // Capacity -----------------------
    size_t size() const { return numberOfElements; }
    bool empty() { return size() == 0; }

    // Modifiers ----------------------
    void clear();

    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition);
    template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool> = true>
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il);

    iterator erase(const iterator& posToDelete);
    iterator erase(const iterator& first, const iterator& last);


    void push_back(const T& d) { insert(end(), d); }
    void pop_back() { erase(--end()); };

    void push_front(const T& d) { insert(begin(), d); }
    void pop_front() { erase(begin()); };

    void resize(size_t count);
    void resize(size_t count, const T& value);

    void swap(List& other) { std::swap(head, other.head); std::swap(numberOfElements, other.numberOfElements); }

    // Operations --------------------
    void reverse();

    // Non standard inefficient functions --------------------------
    T& operator[](const size_t index) const { return begin()[index]; }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Define iterator capability ---------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {

        // Definitions ----------------
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Data -----------------------
        Node* iter{};
        Node* head{};

        // Constructor ----------------
        iterator(Node* const node, Node* const h) : iter(node), head(h) {};
        iterator() {};

        // Dereferencing --------------
        reference operator*() const { return iter->data; }
        reference operator->() const { return &**this; }

        // Arithmetic operations ------
        iterator operator++() { iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { iterator tmp = *this; ++* this; return tmp; }
        iterator operator--() { iter = iter->previous; return *this; }
        iterator operator--(int) { iterator tmp = *this; --* this; return tmp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this;
        };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this;
        };
        // Comparison ----------------- (typical space ship implementation)
        bool operator ==(const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; };
        bool operator !=(const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; };
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter < 0; };
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter <= 0; };
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter > 0; };
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter >= 0; };

        // Special non standard functions -----------------
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const;
        reference operator[] (const size_t index);
    };
};


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation of list functions. This would normally go into a TCC file -----------------------

// List class functions ---------------
template <typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {

    for (Node* nextNode{}, * currentNode(head->next); currentNode != head; currentNode = nextNode) {
        nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
    }
    init();
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous, value);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}

template <typename T>
template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool>>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last) {
    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (first != last) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, *first);
        Iter i(first);
        for (++i; i != last; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, *i);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value) {

    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (count != 0u) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
        for (size_t i{ 1u }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il) {
    return insert(insertBeforePosition, il.begin(), il.end());
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& posToDelete) {

    iterator result = posToDelete;
    ++result;

    Node* nodeToDelete = posToDelete.iter;

    if (nodeToDelete != head) {

        nodeToDelete->previous->next = nodeToDelete->next;
        nodeToDelete->next->previous = nodeToDelete->previous;

        delete nodeToDelete;
        --numberOfElements;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& first, const List<T>::iterator& last) {
    iterator result{ end() };
    if (first == begin() && last == end())
        clear();
    else {
        while (first != last)
            first = erase(first);
        result = last;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end());
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count, const T& value) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end(), value);
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse() {
    const Node* oldHead = head;

    for (Node* nptr = head; ; nptr = nptr->previous) {
        std::swap(nptr->next, nptr->previous);
        if (nptr->previous == oldHead) // Previous was the original next
            break;
    }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Iterator functions -----------------
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::difference_type List<T>::iterator::operator-(const iterator& other) const {

    difference_type result{};
    Node* nptr = head;

    int indexThis{ -1 }, indexOther{ -1 }, index{};

    do {
        nptr = nptr->next;
        if (nptr == iter)
            indexThis = index;
        if (nptr == other.iter)
            indexOther = index;
        ++index;
    } while (nptr != head);

    if (indexThis >= 0 and indexOther >= 0)
        result = indexThis - indexOther;
    return result;
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::reference List<T>::iterator::operator[] (const size_t index) {
    Node* nptr = head->next;
    for (size_t i{}; i < index and nptr != head; ++i, nptr = nptr->next)
        ;
    return nptr->data;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a cpp file --------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {


    List<int> list3{ 10,20 };
    List<int>::iterator l3 = list3.end();
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
        std::cout << *l3 << ' ';
        --l3;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Custom list
    List<int> list2{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (int i : list2)
        std::cout << i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';

    // Delta works
    std::cout << list2.begin() - list2.end() << '\n';
    std::cout << list2.end() - list2.begin() << '\n';

    // Hopp Count works
    List<int>::iterator i = list2.end();
    while (i-- != list2.begin())
        std::cout << *i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the errors that you get, are of course resulting from some wrong coding implementation. And those have been corrected already in other answers.

But for me the biggest problem is the wrong design.

Obviously you are mixing up "Node" with the "linked list". In real world applications the "Node" is a part of a linked list. In object oriented language we have a "has a" relation. So, a linked list has a Node.

Additionally, the whole "Node" functionality would be encapsulated in the linked list. So, the "Node" would NOT be visible to the outside world.

If we interact with a linked list to store or retrive values and such, we would never know about (and even not be interested in) the internas like a "Node".

And, maybe because of that suboptimal design approach, you will create errors.

So, maybe it would be a good idea to refactor your design, and after that, implement it in some better way. For example, use classes, no global avariables and no free functions to operate on list data.

To give you an idea on what could be done, I will show you some implementation of a singly linked list and a double linked list.

Single Linked List:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

// Very simple implementation of a forward list
template <class T>
class SinglyLinkedList {

    // The node
    struct Node {
        T data{};     // Data. Would normally be a templated argument
        Node* next{};   // And the pointer to the next node

        Node(const T& i, Node* n = nullptr) : data(i), next(n) {}; // Simple constructor to set a value and next pointer
    };

    Node* head{};       // This is the start of the list
    // It would be advisable to have a tail pointer. We use the more inefficient approach here
    Node* getLast() const { Node* n{ head }; while (n and n->next) n = n->next; return n; }

public:
    // Constructor / Destructor --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~SinglyLinkedList() { clear(); }

    // Default constuctor
    SinglyLinkedList() {}   // Default
    // From an initialization list
    SinglyLinkedList(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear();  for (const T& i : il) push_back(i); } // From initializer list
    // Copy constructor
    SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }
    // Move constructor. Will steal the elements from the other 
    SinglyLinkedList(SinglyLinkedList&& other) noexcept { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }
    // Assignment operator
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }
    // Move assignment operator 
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (SinglyLinkedList&& other) { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }

    // Housekeeping --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void clear() { Node* tmp{ head }; while (tmp) { Node* toDelete{ tmp }; tmp = tmp->next; delete toDelete; } head = nullptr; }
    int empty() const { return head == nullptr; }
    int size() const { int k{}; Node* n{ head }; while (n) { ++k; n = n->next; } return k; }

    // Modify content --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void push_back(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); Node* l = getLast(); if (l) l->next = n; else head = n; }
    void push_front(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); n->next = head; head = n; };
    void pop_back() { // This is a little bit more difficult in a singly linked list
        if (head) {
            Node* n{ head }, * previous{};
            while (n and n->next) {
                previous = n;
                n = n->next;
            }
            delete n;
            if (previous)
                previous->next = nullptr;
            else
                head->next = nullptr;
        }
    }
    void pop_front() { if (head) { Node* tmp = head->next; delete head; head = tmp; } }

    // Access elements --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    T back() const { Node* n = getLast(); return n ? n->data : 0; }
    T front() const { return head ? head->data : 0; };

    // Add iterator properties to class ---------------------------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {                           // Local class for iterator
        Node* iter{};                           // Iterator is basically a pointer to the node
        Node* head{};

        // Define alias names necessary for the iterator functionality
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Constructor
        iterator() {}
        iterator(Node* n, Node* h) : iter(n), head(h) {}

        // Dereferencing
        reference operator *() const { return iter->data; }
        pointer operator ->() const { return &iter->data; }

        // Aithmetic operations
        iterator& operator ++() { if (iter) iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator& operator --() { Node* tmp = head; while (tmp and tmp->next != this->iter) tmp = tmp->next; iter = tmp;  return *this; }
        iterator operator ++(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; ++* this; return temp; }
        iterator operator --(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; --* this; return temp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp; }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this; };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp; }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this; };

        // Comparison
        bool operator != (const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; }
        bool operator == (const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; }
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return iter < other.iter; }
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return iter <= other.iter; }
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return iter > other.iter; }
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return iter >= other.iter; }

        // Difference. Also complicated, because no random access
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const {
            difference_type result{};
            Node* n{ iter };
            while (n and n != other.iter) {
                ++result;
                n = n->next;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    // Begin and end function to initialize an iterator
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(nullptr, head); }

    // Functions typcical for forward lists ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Easy, becuase we can operate form the current iterator and do not need the "previous" element
    iterator insertAfter(iterator& pos, const T& i) {
        iterator result(nullptr, head);
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* n = new Node(i, pos.iter->next);
            pos.iter->next = n;
            result.iter = n;
        }
        return result;
    }
    iterator eraseAfter(iterator& pos) {
        iterator result(nullptr, head);
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* tmp = pos.iter->next->next;
            delete pos.iter->next;
            pos.iter->next = tmp;
            result.iter = pos.iter->next;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
// Test/Driver Code
int main() {

    // Example for initilizer list
    SinglyLinkedList<int> sllbase{ 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    // Show move constructor
    SinglyLinkedList<int> sll(std::move(sllbase));

    // Add some values in the front
    sll.push_front(4);
    sll.push_front(3);
    sll.push_front(2);
    sll.push_front(1);

    // Delete 1st element (Number 1)
    sll.pop_front();
    // Delete last element
    sll.pop_back();

    // Use a std::algorithm on our custom linked list. Works because we have an interator
    SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator iter = std::find(sll.begin(), sll.end(), 8);
    ++iter;
    --iter;

    // Now add an element after 8
    iter = sll.insertAfter(iter, 88);
    // And delete the 9
    iter = sll.eraseAfter(iter);

    // Use range based for loop. Works because, we have iterators
    for (int i : sll)
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    // Reverse Output
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::reverse_iterator<SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator> riter = std::make_reverse_iterator(sll.end());
    std::reverse_iterator<SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator> riterEnd = std::make_reverse_iterator(sll.begin());

    for (; riter != riterEnd; ++riter)
        std::cout << *riter << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
// Chekcsum
// HazccLR7ffCWA2vBnboBukO3nANVi0KDUi9giVk6jznSZ1fiCUcGCXUEAjyxAN2jT6SEeL28kKdRBnUUh5ztainlpXoLhUKcwGay
// wbfid3BnBBDF7gzh0y7jzY71eVS5zAH1C4rWugWQ8vbhpWL1AtOdAj2PNrwVwUIDVSvuuDHAMW2yQYQfFjZubFYnmJkkqoaP9XCE
```

---

Double linked list. Similar to `std::list`

```
#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a header file -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Type trait helper to identify iterators --------------------------------------------------------
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// The List class ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class List {
    // Sub class for a Node -----------
    struct Node {
        T data{};
        Node* next{};
        Node* previous{};
        Node() {}
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p) : next(n), previous(p) {}
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p, const T& d) : next(n), previous(p), data(d) {}
    };

    // Private list data and functions --------
    Node* head{};
    size_t numberOfElements{};
    void init() { head = new Node(); head->next = head; head->previous = head; numberOfElements = 0; }

public:
    struct iterator;    // Forward declaration

    // Constructor --------------------
    List() { init(); }
    explicit List(const size_t count) { init(); insert(begin(), count); }
    explicit List(const size_t count, const T& value) { init(); insert(begin(), count, value); };
    template <typename Iter>
    List(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { init(); insert(begin(), first, last); }
    List(const List& other) { init(), insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); };

    List(List&& other) : head(other.head), numberOfElements(other.numberOfElements) { other.init(); }
    List(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { init(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }
    template <int N> List(T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }
    template <int N> List(const T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }


    // Assignment ---------------------
    List& operator =(const List& other) { clear(); insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); return *this; }
    List& operator =(List&& other) { clear(); head = other.head; numberOfElements = other.numberOfElements; other.init(); return *this; }
    List& operator =(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }

    template <typename Iter> void assign(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { clear(); insert(begin(), first, last); }
    template <int N> void assign(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> void assign(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    void assign(const size_t count, const T& value) { clear(); insert(begin(), count, value); }
    void assign(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }

    // Destructor ---------------------
    ~List() { clear(); }

    // Element Access -----------------
    T& front() { return *begin(); }
    T& back() { return *(--end()); }

    // Iterators ----------------------
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head->next, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(head, head); }

    // Capacity -----------------------
    size_t size() const { return numberOfElements; }
    bool empty() { return size() == 0; }

    // Modifiers ----------------------
    void clear();

    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition);
    template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool> = true>
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il);

    iterator erase(const iterator& posToDelete);
    iterator erase(const iterator& first, const iterator& last);

    void pop_front() { erase(begin()); };
    void push_front(const T& d) { insert(begin(), d); }

    void pop_back() { erase(--end()); };
    void push_back(const T& d) { insert(end(), d); }

    void resize(size_t count, const T& value);
    void resize(size_t count);

    void swap(List& other) { std::swap(head, other.head); std::swap(numberOfElements, other.numberOfElements); }

    // Operations --------------------
    void reverse();

    // Non standard inefficient functions --------------------------
    T& operator[](const size_t index) const { return begin()[index]; }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Define iterator capability ---------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {

        // Definitions ----------------
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Data -----------------------
        Node* iter{};
        Node* head{};

        // Constructor ----------------
        iterator(Node* const node, Node* const h) : iter(node), head(h) {};
        iterator() {};

        // Dereferencing --------------
        reference operator*() const { return iter->data; }
        reference operator->() const { return &**this; }

        // Arithmetic operations ------
        iterator operator++() { iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator--() { iter = iter->previous; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { iterator tmp = *this; ++* this; return tmp; }
        iterator operator--(int) { iterator tmp = *this; --* this; return tmp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this;
        };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this;
        };
        // Comparison ----------------- (typical space ship implementation)
        bool operator ==(const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; };
        bool operator !=(const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; };
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter < 0; };
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter <= 0; };
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter > 0; };
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter >= 0; };

        // Special non standard functions -----------------
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const;
        reference operator[] (const size_t index);
    };
};


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation of list functions. This would normally go into a TCC file -----------------------

// List class functions ---------------
template <typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {

    for (Node* nextNode{}, * currentNode(head->next); currentNode != head; currentNode = nextNode) {
        nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
    }
    init();
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous, value);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}

template <typename T>
template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool>>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last) {
    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (first != last) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, *first);
        Iter i(first);
        for (++i; i != last; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, *i);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value) {

    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (count != 0u) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
        for (size_t i{ 1u }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il) {
    return insert(insertBeforePosition, il.begin(), il.end());
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& posToDelete) {

    iterator result = posToDelete;
    ++result;

    Node* nodeToDelete = posToDelete.iter;

    if (nodeToDelete != head) {

        nodeToDelete->previous->next = nodeToDelete->next;
        nodeToDelete->next->previous = nodeToDelete->previous;

        delete nodeToDelete;
        --numberOfElements;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& first, const List<T>::iterator& last) {
    iterator result{ end() };
    if (first == begin() && last == end())
        clear();
    else {
        while (first != last)
            first = erase(first);
        result = last;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end());
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count, const T& value) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end(), value);
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse() {
    const Node* oldHead = head;

    for (Node* nptr = head; ; nptr = nptr->previous) {
        std::swap(nptr->next, nptr->previous);
        if (nptr->previous == oldHead) // Previous was the original next
            break;
    }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Iterator functions -----------------
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::difference_type List<T>::iterator::operator-(const iterator& other) const {

    difference_type result{};
    Node* nptr = head;

    int indexThis{ -1 }, indexOther{ -1 }, index{};

    do {
        nptr = nptr->next;
        if (nptr == iter)
            indexThis = index;
        if (nptr == other.iter)
            indexOther = index;
        ++index;
    } while (nptr != head);

    if (indexThis >= 0 and indexOther >= 0)
        result = indexThis - indexOther;
    return result;
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::reference List<T>::iterator::operator[] (const size_t index) {
    Node* nptr = head->next;
    for (size_t i{}; i < index and nptr != head; ++i, nptr = nptr->next)
        ;
    return nptr->data;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a cpp file --------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {


    List<int> list3{ 10,20 };
    List<int>::iterator l3 = list3.end();
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
        std::cout << *l3 << ' ';
        --l3;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Custom list
    List<int> list2{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (int i : list2)
        std::cout << i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';

    // Delta works
    std::cout << list2.begin() - list2.end() << '\n';
    std::cout << list2.end() - list2.begin() << '\n';

    // Hopp Count works
    List<int>::iterator i = list2.end();
    while (i-- != list2.begin())
        std::cout << *i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
}
// Checksums
// W0CqlMhAO8nfQD9IniOhkyEGCnFicc6wpyL3Q03wwz0pgJDrm8DNKRrykxDAiamOs99F66EaDzeeLoq0m3jiHEp1HVgOqoymxM3Q
// AUnIVeK4ER9gyM4qMBU2cZGS0PK6ZKzuhEFCuwbu7UYRBoy4HOdTZ2dclLnUd7fX2uUOUzzdNZluoRCtOatyAgpjqYPMxG02o95j
```